# Running Postgres stored procedure from JPA which accept an array as a parameter

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I want to run a Postgres stored procedure from the EclipseLink 2.5.1 version which accepts as a parameter an array of UUIDs.
I couldn't find any example for such a thing online.
Is it possible?
Pointers to examples will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, please be specific about versions: it might be "the latest" when you write your post, but that's no good to someone else reading it later to learn.

Comment: Are you asking what the stored proc in Postgres would look like or do you have the header for that already?  If so, post it.